# Injecting Angular modules: Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I followed a tutorial on how to organize and Angular project. I have a `ng` directory that contains all my controllers, services and my `routes.js`. This is then bundled all together into an `app.js` by my `gulp` config.

My `module.js` is like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.bootstrap'
]);
```

Here's a bit of my `routes.js`:

```
angular.module('app')
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    .when('/login', { controller: 'LoginCtrl', templateUrl: 'login.html'})
});
```

Here's what my working `LoginCtrl` looks like:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, UserSvc) {
    $scope.login = function(username, password) {
        ...
    }
})
```

The tutorial didn't make use of any Angular modules and I wanted to try one out. I added `ui.bootstrap` to my page from a CDN and try to change the `LoginCtrl` to:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal, UserSvc) {
    ...
})
```

But this throws me the following error:

```
"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $uibModal
```

What is causing this error? In every tutorial I find this seems to be how they load a module, the only difference I see is that the tutorial don't seem to be using a router.

*PS: Note that if I use an empty module list `[]` I get the exact same error. If I use a non-existing module `['helloworld'] I get an error`Module 'helloworld' is not available'. So I'm concluding that my `ui.bootstrap' module is indeed available.*

EDIT: Plunker fiddle here: http://plnkr.co/edit/FWHQ5ZDAByOWsL9YeMUH?p=preview

Comment: Which router you use? angular router or angular ui.router? have you added reference to index page?

Comment: @micronyks I'm using `ngRoute`, I've updated with my `module.js`

Comment: Is there still error?

Comment: @micronyks Yep still Unknown provider error. I've updated question with link to a plunker.

Answer (score 0):

angular route is another module you should not only include but also use like this
in the app module creation

means `DI` of route

`angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);`

Please go through the angular [route doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)

Comment: Yep I am using `ngRoute`. I've updated with how I declare my `app` in my `module.js`. I should have put that before.

Comment: now is it working for u or not ...if not please add a fiddle

Comment: Plunker link added in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ['ui.bootstrap'] form controller. You should add dependencies only one time but you add it twice so the second dependency list override the first one.

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, UserSvc) {
... })
```

Comment: I did that and the error disappeared, but then when I try to : `.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal, UserSvc) {`  to use bootstrap's modal it throws me `Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $uibModal`. So it doesn't seem to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

your routes snippet looks wrong, you should be hanging the when call off $routeProvider and maybe declare $routeProvider as an injected val if it's not being picked up e.g.

```
angular.module('app')
    .config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/login', { controller: 'LoginCtrl', templateUrl: 'login.html'})
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your link. I think there is a serious issue with angular and ui bootstrap version.In ui-boostrap dashboard, it is written that  **0.12.0 is the last version that supports AngularJS 1.2.x**. I have tried with all combinations but it doesn't work with your angular version. 
I suggest you to change angular version to latest and ui-bootstrap version to latest so it will work.

Please check out this working [Plukr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RFNglb3Vdd3Lo5IiSRQe?p=preview)

```
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular-route.js'></script>    //change this to latest also.
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.0.3/ui-bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src='./app.js'></script>
```

If you want to go with your angular version only. I'd request you to do some R&D. Try with different versions of ui-bootstrap. still if it doesn't work you can make PR.